# Plotting Multiple JSON data in flot chart using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, flot

I am using angularjs and JSON to plot flot chart, i am using multiple encoded JSON to draw the line of the Flot line chart, doing so the bar comes out empty.
Not quite sure what is wrong.

HTML

```
  <flot id="placeholder" dataset="dataset" options="options" height="250px"></flot>
```

JS

```
.factory("services", ['$http', function($http) {
 var serviceBase = 'http://maricoih.e21designs.com/services/'
 var obj = {};
 obj.getope = function(){
 return $http.get(serviceBase + 'productionhourlys');
 }
 obj.getcopra = function(){
 return $http.get(serviceBase + 'productionhourlyscopra');
 }

return obj;
}])
  .controller('LineChartCtrl', function ($scope,$http,services) {

 $scope.dataset = [{
      data: obj.getope(),
      label: 'OPE',
      points: {
        show: true,
        radius: 6
      }
    }, {
      data: obj.getcopra(),
      label: 'OEE',
      points: {
        show: true,
        radius: 6
      }
    }];
  })
```

Comment: What format has `obj.getope()`? It needs to be an array of arrays.

Comment: i need to call in the data from my json, the json link is `http://maricoih.e21designs.com/services/productionhourlys`. the JSON is an array of array `[[1931279400,"23"],[1899743400,"23"},[1868207400,"23.16"],[1868207400,"21.27"]]`. how do i fetch this into the "data:" from $scope.dataset

Comment: That looks right. Check in the debugger if the data looks right at the time you call the `plot()` method.